# Getting this error when trying to compile and execute java program from git

Tags: java, git, jenkins, java-17, lightweight-stream-api

```
Started by user Samar Dhiman
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Java-stream-api
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --resolve-git-dir C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Java-stream-api\.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
FATAL: java.io.IOException: Unknown repository format
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.ConfigInvalidException: Invalid line in config file
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Config.fromTextRecurse(Config.java:1236)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Config.fromText(Config.java:1164)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.FileBasedConfig.load(FileBasedConfig.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FileUtils.readWithRetries(FileUtils.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.FileBasedConfig.load(FileBasedConfig.java:128)
Caused: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.ConfigInvalidException: Cannot read file C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Java-stream-api\.git\config
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.FileBasedConfig.load(FileBasedConfig.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.loadRepoConfig(FileRepository.java:212)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unknown repository format
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.loadRepoConfig(FileRepository.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.<init>(FileRepository.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BaseRepositoryBuilder.build(BaseRepositoryBuilder.java:627)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.getRepository(CliGitAPIImpl.java:3593)
Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.getRepository(CliGitAPIImpl.java:3595)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.getRepository(GitAPI.java:347)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitHooksConfiguration.configure(GitHooksConfiguration.java:96)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitHooksConfiguration.configure(GitHooksConfiguration.java:90)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1233)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1305)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:540)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1248)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:649)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:521)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1895)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I want to compile and execute the java code from git I have set up all the configurations like set up paths for git, jdk and maven but getting this error.

This is my repository url - https://github.com/samardhiman007/Stream-Api-Jenkins-Testing.git

And these are the commands that I am using  - javac Main.java
java Main

Comment: Java details are not relevant since the issue is failing with the git repository it never gets to actually trying to building the project. This seems an issue with git or the Jenkins job. Share the configuration of the job.

Comment: this is Git configuration - https://github.com/samardhiman007/Stream-Api-Jenkins-Testing.git
Trigger build - * * * * * 
Batch command - javac Main.java
java Main